# Generating an evenly sized matrix by a given number of elements in python?

Tags: python

I have a python list containing `n` items.

I would like to place the items in an (nearly) evenly sized matrix.i.e the matrix shape should be as close to a square as possible.
Here are some examples.

- number of items 4, matrix size: 2*2
- number of items 5, matrix size: 3*2
- number of items 6, matrix size: 3*2
- number of items 7, matrix size: 3*3

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @PM2Ring sorry, I corrected the question.

Comment: @MohitC I couldn't think of anything useful, I apologize.

Comment: Is the maximum difference between the 2 dimensions equal to 1? Otherwise, 7 elements could go into a 2x4 matrix.

Comment: @PM2Ring the matrix's size should be as evenly as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is as follows:

1. Any number of items `n_items`, must lie between `n^2` and `(n+1)^2`.
2. So to get an "almost" even distribution, we can either have the matrix as `n*(n+1)` or `(n+1)*(n+1)`.
3. Simply comparing `n_items` with the product of these two dimensions will give us the required matrix size. If `n_items` is less than `n*(n+1)`, we'll use `n x (n+1)` and `(n+1) x (n+1)` otherwise.

Here's a sample code:

```
from math import floor,ceil,sqrt

def even_matrix_size(n_items):

    sq_root = sqrt(n_items)
    lower_bound = floor(sq_root)
    upper_bound = ceil(sq_root)

    if n_items <= lower_bound*upper_bound:
        return lower_bound,upper_bound
    else:
        return upper_bound,upper_bound

print(even_matrix_size(7))
```

Comment: thanks, but your solution gives a matrix with size `(3, 4)` for  `9`, whereas it should give a matrix with size `(3, 3)`

Comment: @alwbtc I have corrected the code to include the cases of perfect square. It should work correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it in Python with 2D lists.

For example, if I needed a 5 by 5 matrix, I'd use:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        matrix[i][j] = 0
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

In your case, you need to accept user `input`:

```
size = input("Input the number of elements in the matrix")

Create_Matrix(size)
```

Where `Create_Matrix()` is a function that creates the matrix:

```
def Create_Matrix (size):
    if (size % 2) == 0:
        row = size // 2
        col = size // 2

        for i in range(row):
            for j in range(col):
                matrix[i][j] = 0

    else:
        row = size // 2
        col = size - (size // 2)

        for i in range(row):
            for j in range(col):
                matrix[i][j] = 0
```

Comment: No, that won't work. Eg if the size is 36, then a 6x6 matrix is big enough, but your code makes a 18x18 matrix. BTW, you should use `//` when you want the result of an integer division to be an integer. That works correctly in both Python 2 & Python 3. Python 2 accepts floats in the args to `range`, but Python 3 will not.

Comment: @PM2Ring So basically using floor division instead of normal division?

Comment: Indeed. The docs have been recommending using the floor division operator for that case since (at least) Python 2.4.  FWIW, you can get Python 3 behaviour of `/` in Python 2 by using `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of numpy is best suited here. You could use [`numpy.ndarray.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) to resize your array.

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.resize((3,3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Since the requirement "the matrix shape should be as close to a square as possible" is poorly defined I will present a method that returns the smallest square matrix.

```
import numpy as np

def arr_to_mat(arr):
    arr_copy = arr.copy()

    arr_len = arr_copy.size
    n = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(arr_len)))
    arr_copy.resize((n, n))

    return arr_copy

a = np.arange(6)
print(arr_to_mat(a))
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Note that the function creates a copy of your array and returns a new array without changing your array.